# Convert Windows store javascript app into website

Tags: c#, .net, web, windows-store-apps

I have a simple windows store javascript app, and I am having problems with writing and playback Coded UI Tests. Аnd I had the idea: convert win store js app to website and test it in any of the plurality of web-frameworks.

Unfortunately, I could find information only how to convert the site into an win store app, and nothing on my idea.

How can I convert windows store javascript app into website?? I would be grateful for any information in this matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I convert windows store javascript app into website?? I would be grateful for any information in this matter.

It is not documented, but it's not difficult to convert a UWP(JS) app to a web app. You need to do the following work on your app:

1. Copy all the html,CSS and Javascript(including js libraries) and related assets files to your newly created Web App folder.
2. As there is no application lifecycle in an web app. You need to remove/modify the Lifecycle events in your project. 
   (ex: `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.onactivated` event or `WinJS.Application.onactivated` event if you are using WinJS).
3. Windows Runtime APIs are not available in web app. To avoid errors, it is necessary to remove or comment out the related codes that calls an WinRT API (mostly the APIs that start with `Windows` or `MSApp`). 
   (ex:`Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsyncWindows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsync`).
4. Remove `ms-appx:///`, `ms-appdata:///` and `ms-app-web:///`, replace them with the normal relative path like `../../Assets/`.
5. If you are using `<x-ms-webview>`, remove it or replace it with `iframe`.

Comment: Thx for the answer. I understood the main idea, but what do I do with the functionality that is associated with a variable 'Windows'. For example: `Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayProperties`, `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView`, `Windows.Storage.Streams.DataReader` or `Windows.Networking.Proximity.ProximityDevice` is there any analogues of this functional?

Comment: The functionalities associated with `Windows` are native APIs. They are not available in a web app. So you have to cut them off. For some of the functionalities you can find workarounds by calling browser's APIs (ex: the print functionality).